# "It is raining" or "it is rainy"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, idioms

I'm trying to say:

> I don't like the weather today because it is ____. *(rainy / raining)*
>   I have to carry an umbrella for ____ *(rainy / raining)* weather.

Should I use *rainy* or *raining*?

Also, what is the common rule for using these words?

Comment: The fact that *to rain* is an impersonal verb doesn't tell you whether you should use a participle or an adjective, it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To describe what is actually happening right now, you use the verb form:

> It is raining.

To describe the sort of day it is, you use the adjective form:

> Today is a rainy day.

In your first sentence, either *rainy* or *raining* could fit, depending on what you actually want to say; "... because it is raining" indicates that water is physically falling from the sky right now, while "because it is rainy" indicates that it is the sort of day where rain is extremely likely to happen, but doesn't necessarily mean that rain is falling as you speak.

In the second sentence, only *rainy* fits because it is describing a quality of the weather, not an action.

Comment: "It is raining" alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct. But which one is correct in your case you can validate from below:
"It is **raining**" - Here you are talking about curret state (*verb*).
"it is **rainy**" - You are talking about season/mausam (*adjective*).

Thank you