# I want to know the most common way to describe various weather

Tags: expressions

I've learned the way to say weather with 'if' in my previous query. Now I'm interested to know more about describing weather because it varies depending on the weather.

So they are

> • If it is sunny, ~.
>
> • If it is cloudy, ~.
>
> • If it is windy, ~.

but

> • If it rains, ~.

**Q1.** How about 'snow'?

**Q2.** How about when you simply state the current weather? Is it "It's sunny[or cloudy, windy, rainy, snowy, stormy]"?

**Q3.** How about in this format, 'Today's forecast is ~'? Will the '~' filled with sunny, cloudy, but not rainy and it's "The forecast is rain"?

**Q4.** How about snow? Will it be "Today's forecast is snow"?

Comment: Related: [Is it raining or rainy?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/501/it-is-raining-or-it-is-rainy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sunny, cloudy, windy and stormy all refer to weather concepts, rain and snow are physical weather elements. So you can't say :

- If it suns
- If it clouds
- If it winds
- If it storms

whereas:

- If it rains
- If it snows (hails/sleets)

and you are also allowed:

- If it is rainy
- If it is snowy

but I'm not sure if they sound quite right, so instead:

- If it is raining
- If it is snowing

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> If it is **raining/rainy**, ~

A1 If it is **snowing**, ~

A2 Yes.

A3 I don't think you would use this format. More likely:

> Today's forecast is **for** sunny/cloudy/rainy weather.

or

> Today's forecast **says it will be** sunny/cloudy/rainy weather.

A4

> Today's forecast is **for** snowy weather.

Comment: Ah.. I see there are many ways to say it and 'for' is needed there. Thanks! But 'rainy' is very less used, right? I've learned people prefer verb form for 'rain' but adjective for sunny skies and overcast and windy weather. In fact I wonder when to use noun 'shine'.. Because in my native language, Japanese, we basically tell the weather in noun form..

Comment: I think "rainy" is more common in "rainy day" or "rainy weather", but maybe "It is *raining*" is more common. But you could say 「雨な日曜日」, (rainy Sunday) right?

Comment: You can also say "If it snows".

Comment: It's usually「雨の日曜日」. 「雨な日曜日」sounds creative and possible. :) Yes it's 'rainy Sunday' and to tell the weather we say "It's 晴れ or 曇り or 雨". They are all nouns. Well, I feel 'rainy day' includes the day that it drizzles and clears up for a while and repeat it all day. But I think I'm getting it. Thanks.