# In “Yesterday was X, so I didn't leave the house" should X be “raining” or “rainy”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I heard someone say, "Yesterday was raining, so I didn't go outside of the house,” which seems to be a misuse per [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/504/96188)

To describe what is actually happening right now, you use the verb form:

> It is raining.

To describe the sort of day it is, you use the adjective form:

> Today is a rainy day.

It is the day’s type (rainy) that caused the speaker to remain in the house, so *rainy* is the more appropriate word choice, right?

Answer (score 1):

To talk about the weather, we idiomatically use "it".

> It's raining (now)

> Yesterday it was raining all day.

> Yesterday it rained (at least once)

To talk about the type of weather you might use "rainy".

> It is rainy in Wales (usually)

> Yesterday, it was rainy. It was a rainy day.

<sub>Note  "I didn't go outside of house" is very non-idiomatic.  Use "I didn't leave my home", for example.</sub>

Comment: I had edited OP’s “outside of house” right out from under you :-).

Answer (score -2):

Both sentences are correct. 
"Raining" is a very tricky one because it is actually a gerund. It is functioning as a noun in this sentence.

Comment: I disagree. *Yesterday was **raining*** does not sound at all idiomatic to this native speaker of American English, whereas *Yesterday was **rainy*** is fine. Nor is *raining* a noun (gerund) in that sentence.